# Reexport variables

Tags: bash

I've got script which is RO, I can't modify it. It sets and exports some variables.

This script isn't perfect and so I've wrote wrapper on it. But I've a problem. How I can reexport variables exported via original script?

In bash I can do this:

```
. original_script
```

And I've access to exported variables.
But when I do this in my script I haven't access to this exported variables (because they've been exported from subshell) outside the script.

How I can reexport variables from orignal script in easy way?
Some variables contain spaces, " and new lines.

Comment: If a variable is exported, it is useless to export it again. What is your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `.` (aka `source`) all the way down. You have to source your wrapper, and your wrapper has to source your original script:

Here's a test case showing this works:

```
$ cat original 
echo "Running original"
export VAR='hello world'

$ cat wrapper 
echo "Running wrapper"
. original
```

When sourced by the interactive shell, the variable is available and still exported:

```
$ echo "$VAR"
(no output)

$ . wrapper
Running wrapper
Running original

$ echo "$VAR"
hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

"Original":

```
$ cat original.sh
#!/bin/bash
export VAR1=value1
VAR2='value 2'
export VAR2
```

And wrapper:

```
$ cat wrapper.sh
#!/bin/bash
. original.sh
```

And result:

```
$ echo "$VAR1 $VAR2"

$ . original.sh
$ echo "$VAR1 $VAR2"
value1 value 2

unset VAR1 VAR2

$ ./wrapper.sh
$ echo "$VAR1 $VAR2"

$ . ./wrapper.sh
$ echo "$VAR1 $VAR2"
value1 value 2
```

I always run script by ./script, never by . (or source) ( only for profile files: e.g. ~/.bash_profile etc.). <s>But can I reexport variable by invoking script in normal way? (./script)</s>

I added alias:

```
alias wrapper='. wrapper.sh'
```

and it works. I don't know better solution.